# Unicode encoding when reading from text file

Tags: python, text, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I hope you can help.

I'm trying to take a string and check whether or not it is in a text file called PasswordList. This is the code I have written to do this:

```
Password = input('Enter a password: ')    
with open('PasswordList.txt') as f:
    Found = False
    for line in f:
        if Password in line: 
            print(line)
            Found = True
    if not Found:
        print('Password is not in list')
```

If I put in something like the letter "e", it will return the lines which contain it until it hits position 4583 where it returns an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 4853: ordinal not in range(128).
```

I guess that it has to do with encoding between ascii and unicode, as in Python is trying to use the ascii codec to decode a unicode character?

If I try

```
print (str((sys.getdefaultencoding())))
```

Then I get "utf-8" as the default encoding.

I'm stuck, what can I do?

Comment: does
with open('PasswordList.txt', emcoding='utf8') as f:
work?

Comment: I just tried open('PasswordList.txt', encoding='utf8') as f: and open('PasswordList.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: and neither worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening the file with the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) module:

```
import io
with io.open('PasswordList.txt', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    ...
```

However, you do need to know what encoding the data is in.  The file itself usually doesn't contain this information, you have to know how it was created.

Comment: Ok, making progress!
Now I'm getting a different error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: The first character in the text file is an F ._.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to know what encoding the file is in.  And I can't tell you that.  You need to know how the file was created.

Comment: The file is a .txt file I created using notepad. How can I tell what encoding it is in? Is there an easy way to change its encoding through Python?

Comment: Try opening it with `'latin-1'` encoding.

Comment: @wim Shouldn't we be suggesting to use `io.open()` instead for it's improved newline support?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack yes, I think you are correct.  I've edited the answer so that any future readers will choose the newer `io.open` over `codecs.open`

Comment: @win, more likely on Notepad it is `Windows-1252`...similar to, but not the same as, `latin1`, and also assuming US Windows.  `locale.getpreferredencoding()` should be the actual value.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for your comment.  I've edited the post with your educated guess of the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the encoding of a file created with Notepad, open the file in Notepad. Select File | Save as from the menu. Near the bottom of the dialog, the current encoding appears in a dropdown (screenshot attached).

Now you can try using codecs.open as suggested by wim.

[image]

Comment: Note: This only helps if you're creating and saving a file in Notepad. Notepad won't know the encoding of existing files. `ANSI` means your local 8bit codepage - In the US and Western Europe, this will usually equate to `windows-1252` codec